# instance of child class is gives an error

Tags: java

According to java 7 it is mentioned that we can create derived class instance using base class.
but
 its not working i am trying to implement this concept
 so that i am mention my code over here...
please provide me the solution and solve the problem....
this is the error

```
class A
{
     public void show()
     {
          System.out.println("A class");
     }
}
class B extends A
{
    public void display()
    {
          System.out.println("B class");
    }
}
class Demo
{
     public static void main(String args[])
     {
          B obj=new B();
          obj.display();
     }
}
```

Comment: C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\html>javac Demo.java
Demo.java:24: error: cannot find symbol
                obj.display();
                   ^
  symbol:   method display()
  location: variable obj of type A
1 error

Comment: Are you sure you had `B obj = new B();` and not `A obj = new B();`?

Comment: Compiles and runs just fine for me

Comment: Trying in single java file or multiple file?

Comment: public static void main(String args[])
     {
          A obj=new B();
          obj.display();
     }

Answer (score 0):

If `obj` is of type `B`, as in your posted code, it can't give you an error, since `B` contains the method `display`.

However, based on the error message in your comment - `method display() location: variable obj of type A` - the actual code is probably:

```
A obj=new B();
obj.display();
```

It fails to compile since the compiler determines which methods can be called by the compile time type of `obj`, which is A. Since `A` has no display method, you can't call it unless you cast `obj` to `B` explicitly:

```
A obj=new B();
((B)obj).display();
```

Comment: it is an example of type casting its working but what's the use of that concept which i mentioned....

Comment: @RajeevRanjanSrivastava If your base class A would contain a `display` method, you could call `obj.display()` and it would call `B`'s `display` method. That's what method overriding is. Your `obj` variable can refer to a instance of any class that extends A (or A itself), and the runtime type would determine which `display` method gets executed.

Comment: then what is the meaning of this Line A obj=new B();

Comment: @RajeevRanjanSrivastava It lets you write more general code, since you can call only methods of class `A` on `obj`. But your code would work for any instance of a class that extends A. If, for example, C extends A, you can replace `A obj=new B();` with `A obj=new C();` and the rest of your code (that uses `obj`) would stay the same.

Answer (score 0):

check your file name. make sure that the name of your file is Demo.java... Because when I Compile and run your code, it works. try also to check your java path.